# Grouping excel files by Week Number

Tags: excel

I am trying to work on a Excel that has a giant amount of data with dates, to simplify I want it to group the different numbers into weeks, allow me to explain:

The actual rows are like:

> 29-11-2018 | 49 | 1 | 4 |7 | 2
>   30-11-2018 | 49 | 4 | 0 |2 | 1

Where "49" is the week number from the date. I'm trying to make Excel put together those lines by week and add the other lines, like this:

> 49 | 5 | 4 | 9 | 3

And this for all the weeks, so I can know the exact number of data for every week.
Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks!

Regards,

Comment: Is the number of dates in a given row fixed or variable? What about the cells you are adding? Do you have headers for this table?

Comment: Something like `=SUMIF($B$1:$B$13,49,$C$1:$C$13)` where column `B` is the week number, `49` is the week - can be a cell reference, column `C` is the first column of data.

Comment: Hi Darren, Is this supposed to combine the data rows with the added data cells? I can't seem to make it work and the result keeps being "0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is located at `A2:F3`..

```
H2  --->  =B2
```

put

```
I2  --->  =IF($B1<>$B2,C2,I1+C2)
```

and drag to `L2`, then

```
N2  --->  =IF($B3<>$B2,H2,"")
```

and drag to `R2`. Select `H2:R2` and drag to the end..

you'll see your intended result in column N to R.